# How do I alter a node template from a module in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-modules, drupal-theming, drupal-8

I would like my custom Drupal 8 module to force a different template for pages that match a certain URL. Here is my module structure:

```
/sass_edit
    /css
    /js
    /template
        builder_template.html.twig // this is the template file
    sass_edit.module
    ...
    sass_edit.*.yml // various yml files
```

These are the contents of `builder_template.html.twig`:

```
<h1>test</h1>
```

Here are the relevant lines of code in my `.module` file:

```
function sass_edit_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {

  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();

  if(\Drupal::currentUser()->isAuthenticated() && strpos($current_path, "/builder/") >= 0) {
    $suggestions[] = 'builder_template';
  }

  // kint($suggestions);
  // die();
}
```

When I visit a page whose URL contains `/builder/`, the code runs and adds the string `builder_template` to the `$suggestions` array. However, when the page is rendered, the new template is ignored. I have tried flushing caches, with no results.

I'm not sure how to proceed. All the documentation I've found refers to adding theme suggestions from a custom theme, not a custom module.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Have you enabled Twig Debug? Try $suggestions[] = $hook . '__' .  'builder_template';
Twig Engine had problems with hooking suggestions sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a typo in the code you pasted but the folder where you have your templates overrides should be `templates` and not `template` as you wrote. Don't forget to flush caches after changing the name of the directory ;)